# Ajax & Laravel - cannot populate a textbox base on a dynamic dropdown select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a problem on displaying the ajax data on my textbox, that is my only problem I cannot display the data on the textbox please see my

Code in controller

```
public function create()
{
    $aircraft = Aircraft::all();
    $aircraft_reg = Aircraft::pluck('aircraft_registration_number', 'id')->toArray();
    return view('admin.aircrafts.create',compact('aircraft_reg','aircraft'));
}

public function findPrice(Request $request) {
    $p = Aircraft::select('aircraft_id')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
    return response()->json($p);
}
```

Code in Routes

```
Route::get('/admin/aircrafts/findPrice', 'Admin\AircraftsController@findPrice');
```

Code in View

```
 {{Form::select('productname', $aircraft_reg,null,['class' => 'form-control productname', 'placeholder' => 'Select RPC No.'])}}<br>
    <br>
    {{Form::text('prod_price', '', ['class' => 'form-control prod_price'])}}
```

Code in AJAX

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change','.productname',function(){
            var prod_id=$(this).val();

            var a=$(this).parent();
            console.log(prod_id);
            var op="";

            $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:'{!! URL::to('admin/aircrafts/findPrice') !!}',
            data:{'id':prod_id},
            dataType:'json',//return data will be json
            success:function(data){
                console.log("aircraft_id");
                console.log(data.aircraft_id);

                // here price is column name in products table data.coln name

                a.find('.prod_price').val(data.aircraft_id);
            },
            error:function() {
            }
        });
     });
  });
  </script>
```

There is a warning on my console here.

Here is the warning

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
>   'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to
>   make the page more responsive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952  create:342

Here is the output but nothing is being displayed

[image]

Comment: Please paste here the response after Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel json should have associative array. Something like this:
return json_encode(array("aircraft_id"=>$p));

Comment: will i replace it?

Comment: Console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

Please try change this
$(document).on('change','.productname',function(){

By this

$('.productname').on('change',function(e){

And use e instead this

Please try this and let me how ir workshop :)

Comment: still didnt work sir .. thanks for your response but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery make this changes.

remove var a=$(this).parent();
Change data:{'id':prod_id}, to data:{id:prod_id},
Change a.find('.prod_price').val(data.aircraft_id); to $('.prod_price').val(data.aircraft_id);

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code structure
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.productname').on('change',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var prod_id=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
type:'get',
url:'{!! URL::to('admin/aircrafts/findPrice') !!}',
data:{id:prod_id},
dataType:'json',//return data will be json
success:function(data){
console.log(data.aircraft_id);
$('.prod_price').val(data.aircraft_id);

},
error:function(){
alert("Error Occurred");
}
});


});
```

});

Comment: could you paste the result of this console.log(data); , please. I would like to know what is the server's response

Answer (score 0):

//make sure you have this in your html head file

//Also make sure you have this script in your jquery script before your ajax code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
});
```